# Randomly show arrays objects in the same label

Tags: random, nsmutablearray, label

I'm working on a project that includes 10 questions and answers. I'm using touchesbegan, touchesmoved and touchesended methods. Question appears in one label, and answer has 10 different labels in the screen. Users should match them, basically this is the game. In touchesended method I'm verifying the result of the question and the location of the answer with if statements, so try to understand if it is the right answer with dragged to right place.

So, I need to ask this; the question should be change when the user gives the right answer. I made question on an NSMutableArray, it comes in different and random order for every opening. How can I show some other object of an array in the same label and text. (It should be text because there is another number after that) Here's an example of some code:

```
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];

srandom(time(NULL));
NSUInteger count = [arr count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
    [arr exchangeObjectAtIndex: i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ix1=", [[arr objectAtIndex:(random()%9)+1] intValue]];
```

I need to bring one of the other numbers of an array after the question solved. Also used number shouldn't be appear again.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not remove the object from the array after it's selected once, and next time randomly select from the remaining objects?

Comment: It's exactly what I'm asking. They come randomly and I'm really confused how to remove that random object, cause I don't know which one. I'm really stuck with this code maybe it's too easy but could you help me with sample code?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ix1=", [[arr objectAtIndex:(random()%9)+1] intValue]];
```

you need to get the random index number first

```
int index = (random()%9) + 1;
```

then

```
Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ix1=", [[arr objectAtIndex:index] intValue]];
```

Next you can use the `index` to remove the corresponding object in the `NSMutableArray`

```
[arr removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```